# StreamWriter.Write that returned by a method not working

Tags: c#, console, streamwriter

I have a program file in C# that in some point looks like this:

```
var lowest3Students = studentAVGsOrdered.Take(3);
using var writer4 = GetStreamWriter(folder, "file4.txt");
WriteStudents(writer4, lowest3Students, false);

double AVGTotal = allScores.Average();
using var writer5 = GetStreamWriter(folder, "file5.txt");
writer5.WriteLine(AVGTotal.ToString());

void WriteStudents(StreamWriter writer, IEnumerable<StudentAVG> studentAVGs,
    bool includeName = true)
{
    foreach (var student in studentAVGs)
    {
        if (includeName)
        {
            writer.Write(student.Student);
            writer.Write(",");
        }
        writer.Write(student.AVGScore.ToString());
        writer.Write(writer.NewLine);
    }
}

StreamWriter GetStreamWriter(string folder, string fileName)
{
    var file = Path.Combine(folder, fileName);
    //using FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(file, true);
    return streamWriter;

}
```

I have five files to be created and when I debug the write method, it writes the required data, but when I go to bin\debug and inspect created txt files (5 files: file1 to file5), There are No content inside.
What should be done for this to work?

Comment: Have you closed/disposed the writers before checking?

Comment: @Charlieface he has, read the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing to the file I put this line that solved my problem:

```
writer5.Flush();
```